# stop function in object to execute using flag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Try to write a validation library but stuck on somewhere.

```
var validation_event = {
    mandatory: function(that) {
      if (!$(that).val() && $(that).data('placeholder')) {
        alert('Please fill in ' + $(that).data('placeholder') + '.');
        return false;
      }
    },

    email: function(that) {

      var regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
      if ($(that).val() == '' || !regex.test($(that).val())) {
        alert('Please make sure the ' + $(that).data('placeholder') + ' is valid.');
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wvzbq9h2/

Try to click submit, you will see there are 2 alert. Other than that things are working fine.

Comment: What is your question again? The example works fine in the jsfiddle link you provided.

Comment: @sgarcia.dev stop validation on the first error. there should not be a second alert

Comment: @sgarcia.dev It triggered twice alert which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

check the value of the returned continue validate and return from `$.each` if it is false

```
    continue_validate = validation_event[val](self);
    if(!continue_validate){
      return false;
    }
```

[Updated JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvzbq9h2/8/)

Comment: it doesn't work, the doesn't alert the invalid address. check your code again

Comment: @EuniceChia updated the code. custom element attributes need a `data-` prefix. Validation methods should return true if no error occurs.